# Problem following how the expression with factorial is derived

Tags: calculus

I am looking in my textbook and I am trying to follow this but I get stuck. 
If we look at the model I see that they have swapped with n+1, but when I get to the second last row I do not understand how they have gotten this could someone please take the time to explain?

[image]

Comment: I just do not get how we are able to simplify to get r by itself as well as [(r-n)+n]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start from the first summation:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{r(r-1)...(r-n)}{n!}x^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r(r-1)...(r-n+1)}{(n-1)!}x^n$$

In the first term, if $n=0$, it is just $r$. So we write that by itself:

$$r+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r(r-1)...(r-n)}{n!}x^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r(r-1)...(r-n+1)}{(n-1)!}x^n$$

Then combine the two summations, since they have the same indices now:

$$r+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r(r-1)...(r-n+1)}{(n-1)!} \frac{(r-n)}{n}x^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r(r-1)...(r-n+1)}{(n-1)!}x^n\\
=r+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r(r-1)...(r-n+1)}{(n-1)!} \left(\frac{(r-n)}{n}+1 \right) x^n\\
=r+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r(r-1)...(r-n+1)}{(n-1)!} x^n \frac{r-n+n}{n}\\
=r+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r(r-1)...(r-n+1)}{n!} x^n r\\
=r\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r(r-1)...(r-n+1)}{n!} x^n \right)$$